# Merge multiple rows based on a single column value

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I have an input file like this:

```
  3 1 10 1 6  
  9 4 2  4 1  
  9 2 2  2 1
```

I want to merge two rows based on the 5th column value, the output would look like this:

```
 3 1 10 1 6  
 9 4 2  4 9 2 2  2 1
```

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd lin eof your output. How are you getting to that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With perl:

```
$ perl -lane 'push @{$vals{$F[4]}}, @F[0..3];
              END { $, = " "; for $v (sort keys %vals) { print @{$vals{$v}}, $v } }' input.txt
9 4 2 4 9 2 2 2 1
3 1 10 1 6
```

With awk:

```
$ awk '{vals[$5] = vals[$5] $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " "}
       END { for (v in vals) print vals[v] v }' input.txt
9 4 2 4 9 2 2 2 1
3 1 10 1 6
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command and  it worked fine

```
  awk 'NR<3{$5="";print $0}' filename > o1

     o=`awk 'NR==1{print $NF}' filename`

    awk 'NR==3{print $0}' filename| sed '1i '$o''  > o2

    paste o1 o2| sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"
```